# Translating const strings in structure initializers

Tags: c++, gettext

I'm working with a large code base which uses const strings in structure initializers. I'm trying to translate these strings via GNU gettext with a minimal amount of time.
Is there some sort of conversion operator I can add to default_value which will allow Case #1 to work?

```
#include <cstring>

template<int N> struct fixed_string
{
    char text[N];
};

// Case #1
struct data1
{
    char string[50];
};

// Case #2
struct data2
{
    const char* string;
};

// Case #3
struct data3
{
    fixed_string<50> string;
};

// A conversion helper
struct default_value
{
    const char* text;
    default_value(const char* t): text(t) {}

    operator const char*() const
    {
        return text;
    }

    template<int M> operator fixed_string<M>() const
    {
        fixed_string<M> ret;
        std::strncpy(ret.text, text, M);
        ret.text[M - 1] = 0;
        return ret;
    }
};

// The translation function
const char* translate(const char* text) {return "TheTranslation";}

int main()
{
    data1 d1 = {default_value(translate("Hello"))}; // Broken
    data2 d2 = {default_value(translate("Hello"))}; // Works
    data3 d3 = {default_value(translate("Hello"))}; // Works
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't use `std::string` to store your strings ?

Comment: I would love to use std::string! Unfortunately, this is legacy C code - 200,000 lines of it. The structure bytes are also transmitted over the network as-is, so only POD is allowed unless we do a major rewrite of the entire system. Unfortunately this is not an option right now.

Comment: @bshields: any particular reason why you removed the c++ tag. The code presented in the example is clearly C++.

Comment: Also, the code presented in the example is decidedly not C. You might get better results turning the c tag into a c++ one.

Comment: @Jens Gustedt sorry changed it back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about direct conversion to data1?

```
..
operator data1() const
{
    data1 ret;
    std::strncpy(ret.string, text, sizeof(ret.string));
    ret.string[sizeof(ret.string)] = 0;
    return ret;
}
..
```

and then:

```
..
    data1 d1 = default_value(translate("Hello")); // should work now...
..
```

Comment: Good idea! Problem is that I have other members in the structure besides strings. The code above is just a test case. The actual structures often have over 100 members: strings, floats, doubles, enum values, etc. By using fixed_string, I am able to write a conversion, but then I also have to go update all the arrays to be fixed_string instead. I can do this, but I'm looking for a better option first.

Comment: I opted to go with case #3. There were fewer static-sized arrays than I anticipated, and few side effects from changing them to use the template class instead.